# How to configure lifecycle management for blobs differently?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, lifecycle, azureportal

I am having 5 blobs (i.e 5folders) inside the container, I want to delete the 4 blobs after 30 days and other one after 90 days. So I created lifecycle management rule.

The blobs which I want to delete after 90days, I am identifying that one blob with tags (i.e While uploading folder to container I have added tags).

To satisfy the above conditions I have created two rules

Here is the rule:

```
{
    "rules": [
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "rule1",
        "type": "Lifecycle",
        "definition": {
          "actions": {
            "baseBlob": {
              "delete": {
                "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 30
              }
            },
            "snapshot": {
              "delete": {
                "daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 30
              }
            }
          },
          "filters": {
            "blobTypes": [
              "blockBlob",
              "appendBlob"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "rule2",
        "type": "Lifecycle",
        "definition": {
          "actions": {
            "baseBlob": {
              "delete": {
                "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 90
              }
            }
          },
          "filters": {
            "blobIndexMatch": [
              {
                "name": "Folder",
                "op": "==",
                "value": "cvad"
              }
            ],
            "blobTypes": [
              "blockBlob",
              "appendBlob"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

1. How can I validate my rules immediately (Whether it is correct or not)? Because when I read some blogs it says it take 24 hours to execute
2. Can any one please assist/suggest me if I am doing correct or not? Here my doubt is when Rule:1 is executing I think it also delete all the blobs including the blob with tags as it got satisfied in first Rule.

**Update**

**Note**: Here I used 4 blobs has example, but it can vary like 10 or 20 or 100. So I want to achieve it dynamically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To configure lifecycle management policy with the Azure portal, there are two ways: list view and code view

You are using code view. Instead of that, **try using list view which gives you clear idea.**

- Before configuring lifecycle management policy, make sure to enable blob access time tracking.
- To do that, ***Go to Azure Portal -> Your Storage Account -> Data management -> Lifecycle management -> Select the List View tab -> Check "Enable access tracking" box***
- To add a rule, ***Select Add a rule tab -> Under Details -> Give Rule Name***
- Set Rule Scope to **Limit blobs with filters**
- Select **Base blobs** to set the conditions based on your requirement (delete after 30 days).
- Select **Filter set** to add an optional filter. In that select only those 4 blobs so that rule will be excluded on 5th blob.
- Click **Add** to create that rule.
- Likewise, create another rule by filtering only one blob and select **Base blobs** condition as Delete after 90 days.
- After doing all this, your rules will be created only if the validation passed successfully by showing like below:

[image]

> **Otherwise,to validate it immediately try changing the condition to one
> day and test for one blob**

[image]

For more information in detail, please **find** below links:

**Reference:**
[Configure a lifecycle management policy - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal#list-view)

[How to create an Azure storage lifecycle management policy - (smikar.com)](https://www.smikar.com/create-azure-storage-lifecycle-policy/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. But still I don't know how to select only four blobs by excluding 5th blob because the 4 blob's don't have any prefix match. So I must have a filter that delete the four blobs after 30 days and last blob which I can identify using tags should be deleted after 90 days